# Programa C que calcula idades baseado na data de nascimento

Tags: c

Estou tentando resolver esse problema...

> Escreva um programa em linguagem C que utilize uma estrutura do tipo
> registro (struct) para armazenar os dados de 20 pessoas. Os campos do
> registro são: nome; dia de nascimento; mês de nascimento; ano de
> nascimento. Nenhum outro campo deve ser criado no registro. O programa
> deve calcular e mostrar as idades das pessoas, bem como o nome da
> pessoa mais velha. A idade deve ser calculada a partir dos campos dia,
> mês e ano de nascimento. Para isso, utilize como referência a data
> atual.

Até agora, esse é o meu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define pessoas 2

int main()
{int  i, dias, meses, anos, calculo, diaatual=3, mesatual=9, anoatual=2020, maisvelha;

struct{
char nome [45];
int dia, mes, ano;
}data [pessoas];


printf("\nInsira os dados pessoais:");
printf("\n");

for (int i=0; i<pessoas; i++)
{
printf("\nNome da pessoa %d:\n", i+1);
scanf(" %[^\n]c",&data[i].nome);
setbuf(stdin, NULL);
printf("\nDia de nascimento da pessoa %d:\n", i+1);
scanf("%d",&data[i].dia);
printf("\nMês de nascimento da pessoa %d:\n", i+1);
scanf("%d", &data[i].mes);
printf("\nAno de nascimento da pessoa %d:\n", i+1);
scanf(" %d", &data[i].ano);}

calculo =   365*anoatual + 30*mesatual + diaatual - 365*data[i].ano - 30*data[i].mes - data[i].dia;

anos = calculo/365;
calculo = calculo%365;

meses = calculo/30;
calculo = calculo%30;

dias = calculo;

for (int i=0; i<pessoas; i++)
{
printf("\n%s tem %d anos, %d meses, e %d dias de idade\n", data[i].nome, anos, meses, dias);

if (maisvelha < anos){
printf("\n%s é a pessoa mais velha \n", data[i].nome);
}
}
return 0;

}
```

O programa não calcula os anos corretamente, e também não indica a pessoa mais velha... Ajuda?

Answer (score 0):

Você só saberá quem é a pessoa mais velha depois que calcular a idade de todos. Então não faz sentido tentar imprimir a respectiva mensagem dentro do `for`.

No `for` você deve guardar a maior idade encontrada até então (e o respectivo nome), e sempre ir comparando com a pessoa atual sendo calculada. Aliás, o cálculo também deve ficar dentro do *loop*, afinal, se você tem várias pessoas, cada uma deve ter sua idade calculada. Algo assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define QTD_PESSOAS 2 // dei um nome melhor para "pessoas"
#define TAM_NOME 45

struct {
    char nome[TAM_NOME];
    int dia, mes, ano;
} data [QTD_PESSOAS];

int main() {
    printf("\nInsira os dados pessoais:\n");
    // primeiro lê os nomes e datas de nascimento
    for (int i = 0; i < QTD_PESSOAS; i++) {
        printf("\nNome da pessoa %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf(" %[^\n]c", data[i].nome);
        printf("\nDia de nascimento da pessoa %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &data[i].dia);
        printf("\nMês de nascimento da pessoa %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &data[i].mes);
        printf("\nAno de nascimento da pessoa %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &data[i].ano);
    }

    // calcula as idades de todos
    int diaatual = 3, mesatual = 9, anoatual = 2020;
    int idadeMaisVelha = -1;
    char nomeMaisVelha[TAM_NOME];
    for (int i = 0; i < QTD_PESSOAS; i++) {
        int totalIdade = 365 * anoatual + 30 * mesatual + diaatual - 365 * data[i].ano - 30 * data[i].mes - data[i].dia;
        if (totalIdade > idadeMaisVelha) { // achei alguém mais velho, atualiza a idade e nome do mais velho
            idadeMaisVelha = totalIdade;
            strcpy(nomeMaisVelha, data[i].nome);
        }

        int anos = totalIdade / 365;
        totalIdade = totalIdade % 365;

        int meses = totalIdade / 30;
        totalIdade = totalIdade % 30;

        int dias = totalIdade;
        printf("\n%s tem %d anos, %d meses, e %d dias de idade\n", data[i].nome, anos, meses, dias);
    }
    printf("\n%s é a pessoa mais velha \n", nomeMaisVelha);
    return 0;
}
```

Veja que `idadeMaisVelha` começa em `-1`, assim qualquer valor que for calculado com certeza será maior que ela. Dentro do `for`, eu verifico se a idade calculada é maior que `idadeMaisVelha` (que conterá a maior idade calculada até o momento). Ao final do *loop* ela terá a idade da pessoa mais velha (e `nomeMaisVelha` terá o respectivo nome).